# Word VBA: Get table that is on the display screen at the moment

Tags: vba, ms-word

Suppose you have a microsoft word file (.DOCX), you open it and start to view it, using the mouse scrolling, from page 1 towards the last page.

Then, suppose you see a table, for instance, on page 4.

Now I ask: is it possible for Word-VBA to say to you what is the index or name of that table that is on the screen at the moment, no matter where is cursor located?

I want word-VBA fullfil a table that I am seeing at that moment, no matter where the cursor is located.

I hope I was clear enough...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Word doesn't have a direct way to get what's visible on-screen. It can be calculated, sort of, but not with 100% accuracy.

The following code sample does the trick for me, on my machine. It may need some tweaking to work on a different set up.

The object model does return the co-ordinates of the application window (`ActiveWindow`, here), the height of that Window *and* the `UsableHeight` - the height of the actual document working space. That can be used to get an estimated position.

There's also a Windows API function equivalent - `RangeFromPoint` -  for a `Window` object that returns the a `Range` in the document for the given screen co-ordinates.

This code calculates a left and top position for the start of the visible part of the document, as well as for the end of the visible document. (In my test, it was a bit more, but not much). It then checks whether there is one or more tables within that scope. If it is, it takes the first one ( `Set tbl = rngTargetStart.Tables(1)`) - this returns the object your code needs to work with. As a "bonus", the code prints the index number of the table in the document and the page it's on to the Immediate Window.

```
Sub CheckForTableOnPage()
    Dim WordWindowTop As Long   'in points
    Dim WordWindowLeft As Long  'in points
    Dim windowUsableHeight As Long 'in points
    Dim rngTargetStart As Range
    Dim rngTargetEnd As Range
    Dim pageNumberTarget As Long
    Dim tbl As Table

    WordWindowTop = ActiveWindow.height
    WordWindowLeft = ActiveWindow.left
    windowUsableHeight = ActiveWindow.UsableHeight
    RibbonFactor = 200
    Set rngTargetStart = ActiveWindow.RangeFromPoint(WordWindowLeft, WordWindowTop - windowUsableHeight)
    Set rngTargetEnd = ActiveWindow.RangeFromPoint(WordWindowLeft, WordWindowTop + windowUsableHeight)
    rngTargetStart.End = rngTargetEnd.End
    If rngTargetStart.Tables.Count >= 1 Then
        pageNumberTarget = rngTargetStart.Information(wdActiveEndPageNumber)
        Set tbl = rngTargetStart.Tables(1)
        rngTargetStart.Start = ActiveDocument.Content.Start
        Debug.Print "The table on page " & pageNumberTarget & " is number: " & rngTargetStart.Tables.Count
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: very clever solution indeed!! Even if I knew (until now I didn't) about the ActiveWindow object and its methods and properties, I think I would never have the idea of using RangeFromPoint method and then this line of code: rngTargetStart.End = rngTargetEnd.End. I was wondering why you use the line "rngTargetStart.Start = ActiveDocument.Content.Start". I asked this question using my job account, so I will only be able to confirm my chosen answer at friday, I am sorry. Thank you Sir!!!

Comment: @sergiotrajano I use the line you question in order to get a `Range` that extends from the range on-screen back to the start of the document in order to count the tables up to that point. I only do this because the question mentions "what is the index or name of that table". It's not necessary for working with the table, as we already have the `tbl` object, but just in case you really want that information.

Comment: @sergiotrajano Ah, I see I left an assignment to `RibbonFactor` in the code - that will produce an error as I removed the declaration. I originally had that to account for space at the top before I remembered `UsableHeight`. I will need to delete that later, when I'm not on a mobile device.

Comment: Oh, sure! Shame on me I didn't realize that (get the "absolute" index of the table). I am sorry and thanks for the enlightenment! Yes, I saw that line (RibbonFactor = 200) and immediately realize that it was from the "former algorithm".